# Send email using indy component delphi xe2 SSL negotiation faild

Tags: delphi, smtp, delphi-xe2, indy10

I tried with Indy component to send email in XE2, and it works fine on my laptop that I compiled my project on.

But if I take my exe project to another PC, it shows an error message

> Connection closed gracefully

or, sometimes I get

> SSL Negotiation failed

Actually I tried many times to solve my problem, but I can't.

This is my code - where is my mistake? I need a practical solution.

```
procedure Gmail(username, password, totarget, subject, body :string);
var
   DATA : TIdMessage;
   SMTP : TIdSMTP;
   SSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
   result:Boolean;
begin
   try
      SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
      DATA := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

      SSL.Destination := 'smtp.gmail.com:587';
      SSL.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      //  SSL.MaxLineAction.maException;
      SSL.Port:= 587;
      SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      SSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode :=  [];
      SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

      DATA.From.Address := username;
      DATA.Recipients.EMailAddresses := totarget;
      DATA.Subject := subject;
      DATA.Body.Text := body;

      if FileExists('D:\Test1.txt') then
         TIdAttachmentFile.Create(DATA.MessageParts, 'D:\Test1.txt');

      SMTP.IOHandler := SSL;
      SMTP.Host := 'smtp.live.com';
      SMTP.Port := 587 ;
      SMTP.Username := username;
      SMTP.Password := password;
      //  SMTP.SASLMechanisms;
      SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

      try
         try
           SMTP.Connect;
           SMTP.Send(DATA);
           Result := True;
         except
           on E:Exception do
           begin
               ShowMessage('Cannot send E-Mail: ' + E.Message);
               Result := False;
           end;
         end;
      finally
         if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
      end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error in the function SendEmailDelphi: ' + E.Message);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
mail_username := 'email@gmail.com';
mail_password := 'pass';
mail_to := 'email@gmail.com';
mail_subject := 'Text email from Delphi project';
mail_body := 'this is a test email sent from Delphi project, do not reply';

 try
   begin
     Gmail(mail_username, mail_password, mail_to , mail_subject, mail_body);
   end;
 finally

 end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you have the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll installed in the other PC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Gmails Outgoing SMTP from DELPHI(Indy) using TLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037929/using-gmails-outgoing-smtp-from-delphiindy-using-tls)

Comment: @tomBrunberg ,  I install the dll files in my project folder, and i copy the dll file to system files..
and the problem still not solved !!

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT set the `SSL.Destination`, `SSL.Host`, or `SSL.Port` properties manually! `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` handles that for you. Besides, don't you think it's odd that you are setting `SSL.Destination/Host` to `smtp.gmail.com` but are setting `SMTP.Host` to `smtp.live.com` instead?  Gmail and Live are not the same service provider.

Also, `SSL.SSLOptions.Mode` should be set to `sslmClient` instead of `sslmUnassigned`.  Not too important, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` will simply flip it when it configures the connection.  But you should do it anyway, since you know your code is acting as a client.

And lastly, try setting `SMTP.UseTLS` *before* setting `SMTP.Port`, as setting `UseTLS` *may* change the `Port`, so you want to make sure you are really connecting to the correct port you are expecting.

With that said, the `SSL Negotiation failed` error means the TLS handshake was started but failed part-way through the negotiation. Try assigning handlers to `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`'s `OnStatusInfo/Ex` events to see how far the handshake is actually getting.  And if you are using a relatively modern version of Indy 10, try looking at the raised exception's `InnerException` property, it might give you a clue as to what went wrong before the `EIdTLSClientTLSHandShakeFailed` exception was raised afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much , the problem solved,
................................
But , onther problem was raised to me !!!
'Could not load SSL Library'
I copy dll files library32.dll & ssleay32.dll to my project folder,
but this problem still show to me !!

.............................
how I can solve it ?

Comment: Indy has a `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit that returns why OpenSSL could not be loaded. Either the DLLs themselves could not be loaded into memory, or you are using a version of the DLLs that is missing one or more exported functions that Indy deems "critical" for its use.

Comment: I have a similar problem I have not been able to fix. The code is developed on a W7 Desktop top and it works fine there (and also on another Desktop W10). However, it fails on ReadTimeOut execption on a number of Laptops I have tried.

Note. It used to work fine on a Laptop also, but there have been some recent change which has caused it stop working. I suspect Windows Update.

I have tried the fixes suggested above, but the problem Still Persists.