# Delphi: Using Indy 10 SMTP with SSL and office365

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, office365, indy10

This is a follow up question to [Using INDY 10 SMTP with Office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734414/using-indy-10-smtp-with-office365) and [Cannot use secure SMTP connection to Office365 with Delphi 2010 and Indy 10.5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740921/cannot-use-secure-smtp-connection-to-office365-with-delphi-2010-and-indy-10-5-5).

I have the following routine, incorporating points made in both threads (specifically, I set `IdSMTP.AuthType := satSASL`, provide the most common SASL mechanisms for TIdSMTP to choose from and I use Explicit TLS and `sslvTLSv1`):

```pascal
procedure TEmailAlertSuite.AddSslHandler(const Username, Password: string);
var
  SASLAnonymous: TIdSASLAnonymous;
  SASLDigest: TIdSASLDigest;
  SASLLogin: TIdSASLLogin;
  SASLOTP: TIdSASLOTP;
  SASLMD5: TIdSASLCRAMMD5;
  SASLPlain: TIdSASLPlain;
  SASLSHA1: TIdSASLCRAMSHA1;
  SASLSkey: TIdSASLSKey;
  UserPassProvider: TIdUserPassProvider;
begin
  FSmtp.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(FSmtp);
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(FSmtp.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;

  FSmtp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  // When we explicitly assign the port, we just get connection timeouts...
//  FSmtp.Port := 587;

  // This needs to be true, so that TIdSMTP can decide which SASL to use,
  // from the ones provided below.
  // (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734414/using-indy-10-smtp-with-office365)
  FSmtp.UseEhlo := True;

  FSmtp.Username := Username;
  FSmtp.Password := Password;
  FSmtp.AuthType := satSASL;

  UserPassProvider := TIdUserPassProvider.Create;
  UserPassProvider.Username := Username;
  UserPassProvider.Password := Password;

  // SASL mechanisms are declared and added in descending order of security
  // (as far as that can be known -- not all units give a value for FSecurityLevel).
  SASLOTP := TIdSASLOTP.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLOTP.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLOTP;

  SASLSkey := TIdSASLSKey.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLSkey.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLSKey;

  SASLSHA1 := TIdSASLCRAMSHA1.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLSHA1.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLSHA1;

  SASLMD5 := TIdSASLCRAMMD5.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLMD5.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLMD5;

  SASLLogin := TIdSASLLogin.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLLogin.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLLogin;

  SASLDigest := TIdSASLDigest.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLDigest.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLDigest;

  SASLPlain := TIdSASLPlain.Create(FSmtp);
  SASLPlain.UserPassProvider := UserPassProvider;
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLPlain;

  // (least secure)
  SASLAnonymous := TIdSASLAnonymous.Create(FSmtp);
  FSmtp.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := SASLAnonymous;

  FSmtp.ValidateAuthLoginCapability := False;
end;
```

I set `FSmtp.ValidateAuthLoginCapability := False;` and `FSmtp.UseEhlo := True;`, so that `TIdSMTP` would decide for itself which SASL mechanism to use.

Notice, too, that I had to comment out the explicit assignment of the port. This is because we would get a socket timeout, when assigning it. This is despite following the advice in [Send email using indy component delphi xe2 SSL negotiation faild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241917/send-email-using-indy-component-delphi-xe2-ssl-negotiation-faild), and making the assignment after setting `UseTLS` to `utUseExplicitTLS`.

When I run this on my O365 tenant, I get the following log output, which shows the capabilities of the tenant and an exception:

```
FSmtp.Capabilities:
 SIZE 157286400
 PIPELINING
 DSN
 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 STARTTLS
 8BITMIME
 BINARYMIME
 CHUNKING
 SMTPUTF8
2020-06-02 10:12:46.232 - Doesn't support AUTH or the specified SASL handlers!!
```

Notice there is no announced value for `AUTH`.

I'm not sure what to try next. At this point, I expected TIdSMTP to be able to determine the correct mechanism to use and to successfully connect and send email. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: For Office 365 (and most other SMTP servers), you must use `Port=587` with `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` (otherwuse, you can use `Port=993` with `UseTLS=utUseImplicitTLS`). And `ValidateAuthLoginCapability` is used only with `AuthType=satDefault`, not with `AuthType=satSASL`. And you should be using the IOHandler's `SSLOptions.SSLVersion` instead of its `SSLOptions.Method`, and you should enable TLS 1.1 (`sslvTLSv1_1`) and TLS 1.2 (`sslvTLSv1_2`) in it.

Comment: Regarding the server's reported capabilities, what you showed are the server's pre-`STARTTLS` capabilities. Once a `STARTTLS` command has been issued and the connection is secured, the capabilities will change accordingly (the client is required to send a new `EHLO` command after `STARTTLS` is successful), which will include new `AUTH` schemes appearing, and the `STARTTLS` capability disappearing. When `TIdSMTP` attempts to authenticate with the server, it will first issue the `STARTTLS` and `EHLO` commands for you (when using `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS`) before logging in.